# How to Stop Visual Studio 2010 from updating the designer files's Runtime Version Comment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just joined a new project and the compiled source code of my team member has the Runtime version comment "4.0.30319.1" placed on every *.g.cs. I installed the latest visual studio with service packs and tried to run our project but suddenly my SVN icons have turned red on most files because Visual Studio 2010 automatically changed the Runtime Version comments to "4.0.30319.269" on all the *.g.cs files even though I did not change those files.

Is there a way to stop Visual Studio 2010 from doing this? I would change and commit all the changed files but then my teammate will have several files in red.

I know some may suggest to ask all team mate to install the same service pack and runtime, but I would like to know if this feature can be turned off.